# Finding element in Selenium + Python with repeating classes

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium + Python to scrape match results on a Battlefy page for later manipulation and entering into a database. I'm trying to scrape the names of the teams and the results using Selenium because the dynamically loading JS requires me to use a headless browser. However, I'm trying to get the text of each college using the class name, but using Selenium's `find_elements_by_class_name` method doesn't seem to be working.

Web page: https://battlefy.com/college-league-of-legends/2020-north-conference/5de98dd4196d1311d9e6edbd/stage/5e23b6e395e72856dac06997/bracket/1

Current code:

```
>>> chrome_path = r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe"
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
>>> driver.get("https://battlefy.com/college-league-of-legends/2020-north-conference/5de98dd4196d1311d9e6edbd/stage/5e23b6e395e72856dac06997/bracket/1")
>>> team = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("team-name overflow-ellipsis float-right")
>>> for item in teams:
    print(item.text)
```

Which does not print anything and returns an empty array. I must be doing something incorrectly. How can I scrape each team name's text when it's covered by a class name?

Comment: try with `team = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("team-name.overflow-ellipsis.float-right")`

Comment: That did the trick. For future reference, when referencing by class name, will I always need to place dots in place of white space? @supputuri

Answer (score 1):

`team-name overflow-ellipsis float-right` is combination of classes and when you use `find_elements_by_class_name`/`find_element_by_class_name` method, the locator will be converted to CSS internally but selenium library. Hence you have to mask all the spaces (white spaces) with `.`.

Try with below.

```
team = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("team-name.overflow-ellipsis.float-right")
```

**Edit 1:**

Here is the selenium implementation, where we can see the locator is pre-pended with `.` and it uses `By.CSS_SELECTOR` internally. So, we don't have to add `.` for the first class name.

[image]

Comment: Provided the explanation for reference,hope that explanation helps you to understand the logic behind using `.`.

Comment: `team-name.overflow-ellipsis.float-right` as `class_name` is actually incorrect. It should have been `.team-name.overflow-ellipsis.float-right` as `css_selector`

Comment: @DebanjanB Added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the names of the teams using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)  and *Python* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://battlefy.com/college-league-of-legends/2020-north-conference/5de98dd4196d1311d9e6edbd/stage/5e23b6e395e72856dac06997/bracket/1")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".team-name.overflow-ellipsis.float-right")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://battlefy.com/college-league-of-legends/2020-north-conference/5de98dd4196d1311d9e6edbd/stage/5e23b6e395e72856dac06997/bracket/1")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='team-name overflow-ellipsis float-right']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Cougars', 'University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign', 'Maryville Esports', 'Michigan State University', 'Purdue University', 'Illinois Wesleyan Titans', 'UMN Varsity Gold', 'UC LoL A Team', 'Arbor Esports', 'CWRU 300 Spartans', 'Bethany Esports', 'BGC at OSU', 'University of Wisconsin', 'CGC UIC', 'Indiana University - Purdue University Indianapolis - High Tempo Gaming', 'Missouri State University', 'KSU Wildcats', 'University of Manitoba Bisons', 'Nebraska', 'S&T eSports', 'Illinois State University - Redbird Esports', 'WUSTL Bears', 'University of Iowa A Team', 'TSUES', 'Division 2+', 'Grizzlies', 'Principia College esports', 'Northwestern Varsity', 'Wright State University - Raiders', 'Milwaukee School of Engineering - Raiders', 'UPIKE Esports', 'UMDads', 'Jayhawk Esports', 'NKU Esports', 'Warriors', 'Spartans', 'ND Lol', 'SDSU Team Alpha', 'Rose-Hulman', 'SIUe eSports', 'UND', 'MTU GOLD', 'Polar Bears', 'Purdue Fort Wayne Esports', 'CSU LOL', 'Aquinas Esports', 'Shawnee State Bears', 'Lewis Flyers', 'NDSU League of Legends Club', 'South Dakota Mines - Hardrockers', 'GVSU Laker Legends', 'G&E Club @ Iowa State University', 'MVC Vikings', 'Match from North (Dukes)']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```